# Showing the maximal ideal of a certain local ring is non-principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I would like to show directly that the local (Noetherian commutative) ring $R = (k[x,y]/(xy))_{(x,y)}$ is non-regular, where $k$ is a field.

I have managed to show it has dimension 1, so it remains to show that its max ideal $M = xR + yR$ is non-principal.

Here I am stuck. Is there any way to proceed other than writing out all possible elements of $R$ as fractions of elements of the form $c + xf(x) + yg(y)$ for a constant $c \in k$ and polynomials $f,g \in k[t]$?

Comment: There are several approaches one can take depending on exactly how direct you want to be. Perhaps the simplest is to use the grading of $k[x,y]/(xy)$ and argue by degree.

Comment: Use Nakayama to compute the minimum number of generators as the dimension of a certain vector space.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia gives the following characterization: local $(R,m)$ is regular iff $$\dim_{R/m}{\!(m/m^2)}=\dim{\!(R)}$$ where the dimension on the left is the usual dimension of a vector space, but the dimension on the right is Krull dimension.

In your case, $m=(x,y)$, $m^2=(x^2,y^2)$, and $R/m=k$.  Also, you already know that $\dim{\!(R)}=1$.  Thus it suffices to show that $m/m^2$ contains two linearly independent vectors.

What do you know about $ax+by$?